# Missing font from app site

Tags: macos

I'm running High Sierra on my iMac. Occasionally I'll respond to a request, that pops up on my screen, to read about an app or to try it. Sometimes when I do that a window pops up that looks like the one below.

[image: gibberish_screen]

I don't know what to make of this. Is there a font missing on my machine or is this a problem on the other end? Once I clicked in what I thought was the positive response box but it was followed by a similar pop-up. Anyone know what to do about this so I can read it or contact the site?

Comment: How do I find the question that was previously asked?

Comment: Nevermind. i found it...